# How to manipulate/set reactions to the selection of a drop down menu?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, drop-down-menu

I am trying to make appear a second drop-down menu, which depends on the reaction/choosing of the first drop-down menu's selection. I want to have a 2nd drop-down menu appear which is dependent on the selection of the first drop-down menu.

Iv tried using if statements, but those have not helped me advance.

```
    <select id="countries">
        <option id="US" value="unitedStates" > United States </option>
        <option id="CA" value="canada" > Canada </option>
    </select>

<script type="text/javascript">
    //Global variable for the Countries drop down menu
    var country = document.getElementById('countries');

</script>
```

I want to have a second drop-down menu appear with a list of cities in either the US or Canada, depending on which is selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```js
var cities = {
  unitedStates: ["New York", "Washington"],
  canada: ["Toronto", "Ottawa"]
}

var country = document.getElementById('countries');
var city = document.getElementById('cities');

country.onchange = () => {
    let v = cities[country.value];
    city.innerHTML = v ? v.map(c => `<option id="${c}" value="${c}">${c}</option>`) : '';
}
```

```html
<select id="countries">
    <option></option>
    <option id="US" value="unitedStates" > United States </option>
    <option id="CA" value="canada" > Canada </option>
</select>
<select id="cities"></select>
```

Here we change every options in second `<input>` depending on selection in first `<input>`. Data is taken from `cities` object.

---

UPD: if you dont need empty value in first combo

```js
var cities = {
  "United States": ["New York", "Washington"],
  "Canada": ["Toronto", "Ottawa"]
}

var districts = {
  "New York": ["District 1", "District 2"],
  "Washington": ["District 3", "District 4"],
  "Toronto": ["District 5", "District 6"],
  "Ottawa": ["District 7", "District 8"]
}

let option = d => `<option id="${d}" value="${d}">${d}</option>`;
var country = document.getElementById('countries');
var city = document.getElementById('cities');
var district = document.getElementById('districts');

country.innerHTML = Object.keys(cities).map(option);
linkComboBoxes(country, city, cities);
linkComboBoxes(city, district, districts);

function linkComboBoxes(input1, input2, data) {
  input1.onchange = () => {
    input2.innerHTML = data[input1.value].map(option);
    input2.onchange && input2.onchange();
  }
  input1.onchange();
}
```

```html
<select id="countries"></select>
<select id="cities"></select>
<select id="districts"></select>
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you! Is there a way I can set the default selection to the United States? So that when the page is loaded originally, it is set to the United States?

Comment: Not for the first value, no. I tried having `selected` in front of the selection (like this) `<select id="countries">
    <option></option>
    <option id="US" value="unitedStates" selected > United States </option>

    <option id="CA" value="canada" > Canada </option>
</select>` But this did not work